# Why JAVA program is giving wrong answer?

Tags: java

I recently went through the following question:

> What is the value of `d` after this line of code has been executed?

```
double d = Math.round ( 2.5 + Math.random() );
```

How is the answer for this question equal to 3?

Comment: lets break this down, what does `Math.random()` return? What does `Math.round` do?

Comment: Because Math.random gives you something between 0 and 1. 2.5 plus that is something beween 2.5 and 3.499999. If you round that, it is alsways 3.

Comment: And what do you think is "wrong" about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Math.random() method returns a number greater than or equal to 0 
and less than 1. Since we can then be sure that the sum of that number 
and 2.5 will be greater than or equal to 2.5 and less than 3.5,
we can be sure that Math.round() will round that number to 3.
So 3 is the answer.

Answer (score 9):

Because `Math.Random()` returns a value between 0 (inclusive) and 1 (exclusive) thus resulting in 2.5 to 3.4999999999 which is rounded mathematicly (`Math.Round()`) to 3 no matter what type.

Comment: 3.49~9, not 2.49~9

Comment: @AxelH thanks. This is why I fail math sometimes :P

Answer (score 4):

**Math.random()** returns a double between 0 and 1 but never 1
(**0 <= x < 1**).
**Math.round()** returns the closest long to the argument, with ties rounding to positive infinity.

So the closest long of 2.5 + x where **0 <= x < 1** is always 3 (3.0 in your case since you have a double type)

Your code is **equivalent** to

```
    double d = Math.round(2.5);
    System.out.println(d);
```

Comment: Is it me or is this the same code as in the question twice? Where is it simplified?

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ the simplification is not really correct since you change the logic of the code. This is equivalent though

Comment: @AxelH am explaining the equivalence of the code, so the OP can understand the behaviour

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ I agree, this is the term "simplified" that bother me. I prefer "equivalent" like you just said.

Comment: @AxelH, I will follow your suggestion, am not´English native speaker :)

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ me neither, so I understand the difficulty ;)

Answer (score 0):

According to official documentation Math.Random() is always returns a double value with a positive sign,greater than or equal to 0.0 and less than 1.0.
and Math.round(long ) returns the closest long to the argument, with ties rounding up.

```
double d = Math.round ( 2.5 + Math.random() );
```

So it 3 because result is always less than 3.50 ; so definitely when we round this number it's return 3 .